# how can I change custom Info.plist key with simple string

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, plist, info.plist

I wanna add a custom key to `info.plist` file but `**Apple**` says it should be unique. so I add the key as `**NSCustomKeyName**` or `**ZSCustomKeyName**.` but it should be read `"Custom Key"` when I do Open `As->Property` List. but it stays same as `**NSCustomKeyName**` or `**ZSCustomKeyName**`. how can I do that?. I mean how can I convert `**CFBundleName**` key to `**" Bundle name"**`.

Answer (score 2):

The key-name / Property List name "translation" is done by Xcode via an internal lookup table. It's not simply a "strip the prefix and put spaces before upper-case letters" process.

For example, when viewing as source, you may have this key:

```
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
```

which, when viewed as a Property List shows as:

```
Privacy - Camera Usage Description
```

If you want to add your own "custom" keys, you are not ***required*** to use a prefix... that's just an easy way to make sure they're unique.

For example, source view:

```
<key>My Key</key>
<string>My Value</string>
```

will show in Property List view as:

```
My Key          | My Value
```

and can be accessed with:

```
Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["My Key"]
```

If I prefix that as:

```
com.donmag.My Key
```

That's how it will show up in Property List view, and I would have to access it with:

```
Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["com.donmag.My Key"]
```